# Smart Pointers In C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, object-slicing, object-destruction

Say we have a `base` class and a `derived`. So:

```
class base {
     protected:
          ~base(){
                //...
          }
     // ...
};

class derived : public base {
     // ...
};
```

And now say that we have this code using the above classes with a smart pointer class:

```
SmartPointer<base> bptr(new derived());
delete bptr;
```

I understand that it would prevent slicing of the `derived` object by calling the destructor of `derived`, but how does it know to do that? Wouldn't the reference stored in the smart pointer be that of type `base*`? Does it traverse some kind of hierarchy tree, cast that pointer to `derived*` and then call delete? Or is there some other thing that I don't know about?

The implementation is supposedly threadsafe, non-intrusive, and reference counting.

**YES**, the classes that you see are akin to the ones that I'm testing against. There is apparently a way to do this with THESE GIVEN classes. The main idea as to how is mentioned in my question above, but I'm not sure as to how one such an implementation would work.

Comment: The above code won't compile, as the destructor of `base` is private, aka non-accessible.

Comment: Which `SmartPointer` implementation are you using?

Comment: @Xeo: I know that it doesn't compile. However I have seen an implementation that does compile and runs correctly, but I have not seen the actual code.

@Charles Bailey: It's supposed to be a reference counting implementation.

Comment: Make sure the destructor of any base class is `virtual`!

Comment: Say that I was designing the smart pointer to fit the criteria in the edit above, and that someone else gave me those classes to work with...any idea as to what a good reference or direction would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing is that as it stands the code will not work. The destructor of `base` must be at the very least `protected` (or derived classes be friends of the base). A `private` destructor means that the compiler will not allow you to write the destructor for the derived classes. Now, assuming that you have a `protected` destructor... (Rembember, if you design a class to be extended, provide either a *public virtual destructor* or a *protected non-virtual*!)

All depends on the implementation of the `SmartPointer`, in particular `std::shared_ptr` (or the boost counterpart `boost::shared_ptr`) are able to manage that situation cleanly. The solution performs some sort of partial type erasure of the type for destruction purposes. Basically, the smart pointer has a templated constructor that accepts any pointer that can be assigned to a `base` pointer, but because it is templated it knows the concrete type. At that point it stores a synthetic `deleter` function that will call the appropriate destructor.

For simplicity, using `std::function`:

```
template <typename T>
void delete_deleter( void * p ) {
   delete static_cast<T*>(p);
}

template <typename T>
class shared_pointer {
    T * ptr;
    std::function<void(void*)> deleter;
public:
    template <typename U>
    shared_pointer( U* p, std::function<void()> d = delete_deleter<U> ) 
       : ptr(p), deleter(d)
    {}
    ~shared_pointer() {
       deleter( ptr );  // call the stored destructor
    }
};
```

The code is for exhibition only, it would have to be tweaked for production (where to store the `function`, reference counting...), but it is enough to give you the idea: in the only function where the exact type of the object is known (when creating the smart pointer), you create a wrapper that will call the exact version of the destructor that you need (providing some short of type erasure), then just leave it around and when you need to `delete` the object call it instead of the `delete` operator.

This can also be used to manage other resources that require calling a special method instead of `delete`:

```
// exhibition only!
shared_pointer<Foo> p( Factory.create(), &Factory::release );
```

Again there should be quite a lot of work before making this production ready.

Dependency on `std::function` which is used to simplify the erasure, can be eliminated from the problem. In the simple case (only memory allocated with `new` and freed with `delete` is supported in the smart pointer), then just provide a `deleter` base class with a single virtual `operator()(void*)`, and then refactor the existing `delete_deleter` into templated derived classes from `deleter` that override `operator()(void*)` with the current implementation. If you need to go for the general case (hold any type of resource) it is not worth the effort, just use `std::function` or `boost::function`.

Comment: +1, but to be picky `~base` doesn't *need* to be `protected` if `derived` is a `friend` of `base`.

Comment: @dalle: the problem with making `friend`s that way is scalability, you will need to modify your base class for each and every new type. Also you are increasing coupling (friendship is a stronger coupling relationship than inheritance, it is the *most* coupling relationship) by allowing access to *all* of `base` private parts. I would recommend against friendship in this scenario *always*, unless there is a strong reason (say that you want to allow only a limited set of derived classes, then the maintainability problem is actually an advantage!)

Comment: íguez-dribeas: I mostly objected to the word **must** in the phrase "The destructor of base must be at the very least protected". I agree with what you say, but in the OP case the use of private may have it's use, as you also describe.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, your destructor shouldn't be private or that won't compile at all. Secondly, if you're using a "smart pointer", you probably should not be deleting the pointer by hand at all (I don't know what implementation you're using though, but this strikes as odd to me).

Anyways if you're curious how the derived class' destructor gets called when the object is deleted through a pointer to the base class, the answer is polymorphism. But you're missing `virtual` declaration from your destructor, right now your code would not call the derived class' destructor.

How most C++ implementations implement this is through a [virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Comment: upvoting you for at least attempting to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

If you using any of boost smart pointers or some other which is not `friend` of your `Base` class, then this code wouldn't compile, because destructor of `Base` class is `protected` (which is same as `private` for other independent from `Base` classes).

Now let's consider that you make `SmartPointer<Base>` friend of `Base`. This case the code will work, but it wouldn't call destructor of `Derived` but destructor of `Base`, because here your `Base` class is not polymorphic. You should declare destrucotr of `Base` as `virtual`. In last case the correct destructor will be called when your smart pointer is deleted.

Comment: It should work for classes like this. Also, it is must not be intrusive. I forgot to add that..I'll do so in an edit.

Comment: How should it work if destructor of your base class is protected, and how should it call destructor of `Derived` if it is non virtual?

Comment: That is actually the heart of my question. I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

this program is invalid.

1) the dtor of base is private

2) the dtor of base is not virtual

to answer your question: you need to correct #1 and #2. *then* the dtor will be called using dynamic dispatch (which will invoke each dtor in reverse order of construction).

without making those corrections, the only way `SmartPointer` could know to call derived's dtor in this example, and in a defined manner, is if `SmartPointer` was overly clever (or tedious to use).

Comment: "overly clever" as `boost::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Yes. It is overly clever (I have seen an implementation that works, but I have no idea as to what the code looks like!)

Comment: @dalle since `boost::shared_ptr<base> bptr(new derived());` is a malformed program, i've failed to see your point.

Comment: @Justin: `boost::shared_ptr<base> bptr(new derived());` is 100% correct. It stores a correct deleter internally.

Comment: @Justin: Regardless if `~base` is `virtual` or not, `boost::shared_ptr<base> bptr(new derived());` is well defined and valid. Even `boost::shared_ptr<void> bptr(new derived());` is well defined and valid. Your first point still need to be addressed somehow, so that `derived` can access `~base`.

Comment: @Justin: It is perfectly valid a well-defined to write `boost::shared_ptr<base> bptr(new derived());`. That's why `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<>` exists. What are you trying to say ?

Comment: @Justin: I have added a sketch of how that can be safely implemented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787033/question-on-smart-pointers-in-c/5787480#5787480)

Answer (score 0):

Your base class desctructor needs to be virtual to ensure that destructor of derived class is called when deleting via base pointer.

[Wikipedia entry on virtual desctructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Virtual_destructors)